# Handling Multiple Race/Ethnicity and Other options in one column in r

Tags: r

I have data from Google forms where the question asks a respondents to check all the race/ethnicity options that apply and gives the option of other. I've been able to pull the data on the checked race/ethnicity into separate columns where the respondents either do or don't identify with that category, but I would also like to pull the responses that don't align with the check boxes into their own column so I can examine those responses separately. Does anyone know how I might go about doing that?

For the below example the check box race options include: African American, Asian, Asian American, Latinx, White. So what I would like would be to pull any responses that don't fit those criteria into their own column.

`df<-data.frame(race=c("African American, Asian, Asian American, Chinese", "Latinx, Portuguese","White, American"))`

Comment: You just want to filter based on certain race?

Comment: I want to filter out those responses that aren't captured by the race options included in the survey.

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated, based on OP's clarification:

```
f <- function(inp) {
  for(cb in cb_races) inp <- gsub(cb,"",inp)
  trimws(gsub(",","",inp))
}

as.data.frame(sapply(cb_races,grepl, x=df$race)) %>% 
  mutate(Other = f(df$race))
```

Output:

```
  African American Asian, Asian American Latinx White      Other
1             TRUE                  TRUE  FALSE FALSE    Chinese
2            FALSE                 FALSE   TRUE FALSE Portuguese
3            FALSE                 FALSE  FALSE  TRUE   American
```

Perhaps something like this?

```
as_tibble(df) %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number(),
         race = strsplit(race,",")
  ) %>% 
  unnest(race) %>% 
  mutate(race=trimws(race),
         race_cat=if_else(race %in% cb_races, race,"Other")
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id,names_from=race_cat, values_from=race) %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(cb_races),~is.na(.x)==F))
```

Output:

```
     id `African American` `Asian American` Other      Latinx White
  <int> <lgl>              <lgl>            <chr>      <lgl>  <lgl>
1     1 TRUE               TRUE             Chinese    FALSE  FALSE
2     2 FALSE              FALSE            Portuguese TRUE   FALSE
3     3 FALSE              FALSE            American   FALSE  TRUE
```

Input:

```
df<-data.frame(race=c("African American, Asian, Asian American, Chinese", "Latinx, Portuguese","White, American"))
cb_races = c("African American", "Asian, Asian American", "Latinx", "White")
```

Comment: So the comma doesn't work as a delimiter. I just looked back at the data and some of the categories themselves have commas so the Asian American category is "Asian, Asian American". I've edited the original code to reflect that

Comment: some of the checkbox categories, or some of the user written categories?. Perhaps show what you expected output is?

Comment: For example ,if a user wrote "Asian, Asian American", in the "Other" category, do you want the end result data frame to ignore that, because "Asian American" is a checkbox category, or do you want the checkbox category to be "TRUE" and the "Other" to list "Asian" as an additional "Other" value

Comment: Yes, Google forms dumps the checkbox responses and user written categories into one column. Don't need to pull out the checkbox categories, I've already done that much. I would just like a column that, based on my example data, to have Chinese, Portuguese, American in it. So some kind of code that says if it doesn't match the checkbox values it should get dumped into it's own column. Hope that helps

Comment: something like my edit?

Comment: Do I need to change the cb and the cb_races to match my dataframe? I'm getting an error saying cb_races not found

Comment: Yes, you have to use the cb_races as I have defined in my Input section of the answer

Comment: I keep getting this error Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : object 'cb_races' not found

Comment: did you create it?

Comment: @asimpfen, were you able to create it? it is just a dictionary of your standard check box terms..i.e a character vector of length n, where n is number of unique standard races (ie non other terms).. you can use the code i provided